# Shift register 74595 does not shift values

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register

I am using a 74HC595 shift register IC connected to my Arduino board to drive 8 RGB LED modules. The LED modules have built in resistors and require a +5V at anode which I provide from the Arduino. Following is a rough schematic of the circuit, the pins numbers correspond to those on the Arduino UNO microcontroller.
[image: Circuit Schematic]
Following is a small code for the same:

```cpp
const int latchPin = 8;
const int clockPin = 12;
const int dataPin = 13;
const int redValuePin = 9;
const int greenValuePin = 10;
const int blueValuePin = 11;

void setup() { 
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redValuePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenValuePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueValuePin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Reset");
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(redValuePin, 0);
  analogWrite(greenValuePin, 255);
  analogWrite(blueValuePin, 255);
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int bitToSet = Serial.read() - 48;
    registerWrite(bitToSet, HIGH);
  }
}

void registerWrite(int whichPin, int whichState) {
  byte bitsToSend = 0x00;
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  bitWrite(bitsToSend, whichPin, whichState);
  Serial.println(bitsToSend);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, bitsToSend);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}
```

However, the shift register does not seem to be shifting values. This is verified as **only O0 is high in MSBFIRST** and **only O7 is high in LSBFIRST** mode of `shiftOut()`, irrespective of the `bitsToSend` value. That is, only the first line is high. Is there any reason in the hardware/software that caused this, or do I just have a faulty IC?

Comment: where are the current limiting resistors?

Comment: Try printing this value out `int bitToSet = Serial.read() - 48;` Depending on how you have configured the serial monitor you may have terminating characters in there.

Comment: The comment about the current limiting resistors is a very important one, especially because you haven't mentioned what those are actually doing. My guess is they are not lit, because they were over-currented and are now open.

Comment: Sorry I haven't shown this in the schematic above but I am sort of using an LED module that has the resistors with it.

Comment: Hint: A Power Supply the Arduino is NOT! You are probably having the arduino's regulator overheating and shutting down. This is a SWAG as the schematic does not show power sources other then the Arduino.

Comment: Yes it is true that I am using the Arduino as a power supply. I will try using an external power supply. Hopefully that solves it.

Comment: This problem has been resolved. As it turns out, the error was with the serial monitor, as it sent more than one value to the variable (the second one causing the bitToSet to be negative). This is most likely due to terminating characters as pointed out by @6v6gt. I guess it is much better to use standard functions like `atoi()` to convert serial monitor data to integers.

Comment: In relation to my previous comment, the problem was due to my Serial monitor adding a NL (new line) character to my inputs, once configured to not do this, the program works fine.

Comment: I guess that qualifies as an answer which you can add yourself and maybe you get a few brownie points. Thanks anyway for reporting back.

Comment: Yeah actually I tried doing that but cannot since the question was closed. I have edited it and submitted for reopening though.